# Text value doesn't change in React Native app using Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have this react native app that shows the splash screen first and loads a home screen. The sample home screen shows text as "Demo Display" and I want to change it to "Text Changed!". I'm using a stateful class component. But everytime I try to restart/reinstall/debug the app the text remains same as "Demo Display". How can I fix this?

App.js

```js
import React,{ Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
      SplashScreen.hide();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Text Changed!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[This is a screen shot of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4jow.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is there on the screen but it will not replace the default text.
Give some style to your main View and you will see your text there.
Try,

```js
<View style={{justifyContent: 'center',alignItems: 'center'}}>
  <Text>Text Changed!</Text>
</View>
```